# Infimum of $\left\{\left|\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{n}\right|\;: \;m,n \in\mathbb{N},\; m≠n\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

In my homework assignment I encountered this problem:

> Find the infimum of the set $A=\left\{\left|\sqrt{m} - \sqrt{n}\right|\;: \;m,n \in\mathbb{N},\; m≠n\right\}$

How do i even start to find the infimum of this set??

Comment: Please look at our guidelines for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with particular emphasis on [formatting and writing your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), from which I take this quote: *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.*

Comment: Do you know what the definition of ``infimum" is? That is likely a good place to start...

Comment: @JWP_HTX yes i know, but i dont get it so easy. I tried to get an element from A and work with, but going to nowhere...

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry, first time posting not allowed to copy a image direct into post ;/

Comment: What happens if m and n are close?

Comment: @martycohen it gets closer and closer to 0...

Comment: $0<\sqrt {n+1}-\sqrt n=$ $\frac {1}{\sqrt {n+1}+\sqrt n}$ $<\frac {1}{\sqrt n}.$

Comment: So what does that tell you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all observe that $\left|\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}\right|\geq0$, So if we will prove that $0$ is the greatest lower bound we are done.

By the definition of the set $A$, we know that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\in A\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ (because $\sqrt{n+1}>\sqrt{n}$ we dont need the absolute value), and after a bit of simplification we would conclude that

$$
A\ni\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n})}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}
$$

Now let $\varepsilon>0$ we will take $n=\left\lceil\frac{1}{(2\varepsilon)^2}\right\rceil$. It happens to be the case that

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}\leq\frac{1}{2\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\varepsilon)^2}}}=\varepsilon
$$

Hence, by an equivalent definition of an Infimm of a set, we will conclude that $0$ is the infimum of $A$.

Comment: now i can see what's going on, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

We have for all $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$, that $\lvert{\sqrt{m}-\sqrt{n}}\rvert\geq 0$. So a lower bound is $0$. You now need to figure out if $0$ is the greatest lower bound (and prove if it is).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @BKHautop I called out the  ε>0 ;  ε=1/k for all k ∈N then i got a<1/k... so it is like a complete solution?

Comment: What? You need to show you can get arbitarily close to $0$. So given an $\epsilon>0$ you need to show there is an element, $a$, in your set $A$ such that $a-0<\epsilon$.

Comment: @BKHautop but how?

Comment: @trickyzerg Another common way (and maybe easier than solution posted by Udi Fogiel) is suppose for contradiction there exists a lower bound greater than 0, call it $l$. If you can show there exists an element, $a$, in $A$ such that its less than your lower bound $l$ you have proven infimum is $0$. So solve $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=l$ and pick an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ greater than $x$ (since $\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}$ is decreasing).

Answer (score 0):

Write $m=n+k$, $k>0$, $m, n, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

0)$0$ is a lower bound

1)$\sqrt{n+k} - \sqrt{n} \ge \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}$,

since $\sqrt{}$ is strictly increasing.

2)$\sqrt{n+1} =\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}$, and $\sqrt{n}=\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n}}$;

3)$0<\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}<$

$\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-
\dfrac{n}{\sqrt{n}}<$

$\dfrac{n+1}{\sqrt{n+1}}-\dfrac{n} {\sqrt{n+1}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} $.

4)Sandwich

5)Show that $0$ is least lower bound.

6)Assume $a>0$ is a lower bound.

7)Archimedean principle

There is a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t.

$n_0>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{a}}-1$, or

$a>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n_0+1}}$, contradiction, and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out, since for $n \ne m$ we have that $|\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{m}|>0$, the infimum is surely greater or equal than zero. On the other hand, since $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})=0$, the infimum cannot be greater than zero.